# how to Update records in database using where condition in android room?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am using android room library to maintain local database.
I am trying to update a row of a table by checking the column value just like where clause.

Currently i am using the below code to update the records,

```
@Update
void update(ProductInfo prodInfo);
```

My question here is, I want to update the record by using where clause, for example my query is;

```
Update ProductInfo set (AllColumns) where prodInfo.last_name = 'xyz';
```

but in room i could not find the answer for that, one option is to write raw query but writing all the column names is very much lengthy.

Can anyone guide me resolving this issue ?

Comment: 1. use raw query or 2. select all with "where", update fields in java, use update with list `@Update
void updateList(List<ProductInfo> prodInfo);`

Comment: @Selvin : I tried implementing this but it is creating another new record due to different data.

Comment: Do not change primary key then the second solution should works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Query("your update query")` to resolve your issue.

Comment: can u please give an example or snippet of how do i write ProductInfo update query for all columns in @Query section..

Comment: `@Query("Update ProductInfo set (AllColumns) where prodInfo.last_name =:lastname")
void update(String lastname, ..columns)

Comment: mehmet thanks for replying on this post. There are 43 columns that is why i am looking for some easy way. Here ProductInfo if my model class defined as @Entity.

Comment: I don't know any other way to do that